# Issues Searching for UUID in Text Document Python

Tags: python, regex

Issues Searching for UID in Text Document

I'm brand new to Python & coding in general.

I'm working with an application that tracks objects and their states. Users can change these objects' states whenever they need to. I've written a script that pulls a UID from the REST API.

Then the UID is written to a text document, and a date / time timestamp is appended so I can see when that change was made.

The only trouble I'm having is searching the text file programmatically to ensure a.) the UID's aren't being added twice and b.) the timestamp isn't being updated (I need to maintain the time date of the original change.

```
def open_write():
  with open('//textdoc.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(uid) + str(x) + "\n")

def open_read():
  with open('textdoc.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read()
  useRegex()
```

This is what the data will look like:

```
a732b7fb-1334-4f11-8306-e57991496cdb']2021-12-20 15:37:58.585338
```

I just can't figure out how to filter the data down on the open_read() using regex.

Comment: Not sure I am understand, why do you want to filter data on read? Shouldn't you don't write uid that already exists in file?

Comment: I'm super new so I had assumed I'd need to read the file and then filter data there. Is there a better way to do it on write?

Comment: Got it - so in case some uid exists in file you just want to ignore write operation? Or put the existing uid on the end of file and remove previous one?

Comment: I'm hoping to append new uid + timestamps to the end only if the UID doesn't already exist in the file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not optimal, as without any kind of sorting you need to check all rows, but you can just use `if uid in ...` syntax

```
def open_write():
  with open('//textdoc.txt', 'r+') as f: # notice different open modifier, as we need read file first
    content = f.read()
    if str(uid) not in content:
        f.write(str(uid) + str(x) + "\n") # this write works because we read file, so the position is at the end, thought effectively append here.
```

To make it faster you could use database with index or use record sorting with binary search, however writing in the middle of file isn't so straightforward as we need to copy all data after the place we want to write new record. Another option is to have this in cache (so some python variable) and flush it to the file in case of error or out of memory but they are just louse ideas.